# Как правильно пишется "как раз-таки"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

"Как раз-таки", "как-раз-таки" или "какразтаки"?

Answer (score 12):

Частица **таки**, которая стоит после глаголов, наречий, частиц (и вводных слов) пишется через дефис: *верно-таки*, *неужели-таки*, *действительно-таки*, *всё-таки*, *ушёл-таки*. В остальных случаях **таки** пишется отдельно, например: *старик таки добился своего, она таки бросила семью, большую таки дачу себе построили*; *...но таки упёк своего товарища* (Гоголь); *...я таки запер её и в этот раз* (Достоевский). Но если частица, которая пишется через дефис, стоит после другой частицы, то дефис опускается, например: *всё ж таки*, *мы бы де так не поступили*. Сравни: *Такой-то де старик... и зол и подл* (Пушкин).

Поэтому правильно будет написать "*как раз таки*".

Comment: Вы сами-то поняли, что написали?

//Частица таки, которая стоит после частиц, пишется через дефис. Но если частица, которая пишется через дефис, стоит после другой частицы, то дефис опускается.//

Comment: Дело в том, что такую формулировку не я придумал. Посмотрите справочник по правописанию и литературной правке Д.Э. Розенталя. Там так и написано. Может, это и не совсем понятная формулировка правила, но автор имеет в виду, что если перед той частицей, которая пишется через дефис, и словом, после которого эта частица стоит, вклинивается еще одна частица (в основном "ли", "бы", "же"), то все три слова отдельно пишутся.

Answer (score 2):

Так и пишется КАК РАЗ ТАКИ. Знаки препинания тут совсем не нужны.

Частица *таки* пишется через дефис в составе слов *все-таки* и *так-таки*, а также в тех случаях, когда она следует за глаголом, например: «Узнал-таки меня». Во всех остальных случаях частица *таки* пишется отдельно, например: «Я таки думаю кое-что» (М. Горький); «И все ж таки я тебя не понимаю».

Answer (score -1):

Сомнительно. Частица -таки, стоящая **после** глаголов, наречий, **частиц**, пишется через дефис. "Как раз" — частица.